# Argument Error First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty for search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am adding a query collapse, however when adding the code I get a `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` error that points to the line `<%= form_for @search, :class => 'content' do |f| %>`

I updated the post with the users and searches controller for a better look.

index.html.rb:

```
 <%= render 'searches/new' %>
```

/searches/_new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @search do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :gender %><br />
  <%= f.select :gender, ['male', 'female'], :include_blank => true %>
</div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :state %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :state %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Original source code:

```
<div class="layer1">
<p class="heading">Header-1 </p>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
</div>
```

Users Controller:

```
  def settings
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
```

Searches Controller:

```
  def new
    @search = Search.new
  end

  def create
    @search = Search.new(params[:search])
    if @search.save
      redirect_to @search
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    @users = @search.users
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty error that
>   points to the line <%= form_for @search, :class => 'content' do |f| %>

means that `@search` is nil. Make sure to set it in the controller's relevant action before loading this view. As you haven't shared the Controller specific code, Its hard to pin point exact location to set the `@search` instance variable.

**UPDATE**

Add `@search` in UsersController#index

```
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @search = Search.new
  end
```

Update the render call in `views/users/index.html.erb` as

`<%= render partial: 'searches/new', locals: {search: @search} %>`

Also, in your partial `views/users/searches/_new.html.erb` update the `form_for` as

```
<%= form_for search do |f| %>
```

Comment: The search form is under the Searches controller. However I am working from the Users controller. When switching the code to render the form (I switched /searches/new.html.erb to a partial) I get the same error. So even in a render I would have to call @search under the show action?

Comment: Yes, you would need to set `@search` in show action so it will be available in the partial.

Comment: What do you think would be ideal? I tried `@search = Search.new` but am receiving the same error. I posted the users controller if you have the time to take a look.

Comment: Where did you post it? I don't see it in the question.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I see it. Which action of UsersController renders the partial? Thats where you need to set `@search`.

Comment: oh sorry I removed the `@search = Search.new` from the show action since it was still giving me the same error. I didn't think it would be helpful to leave it there for you to see.

Comment: See UPDATE in my answer. Try it out and let me know.

Comment: Thanks. I also made a mistake as I needed to move it to the index action, not the show action. I've never done `locals:` so I will read into that. Thanks again!

Comment: Thats what I was wondering. I thought it should have been in index action. Anyways, glad its resolved. I'll update my answer:)